# How to attach an Authorization header with a token when using Leaflet js

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, authorization, fetch, interceptor

I am using Leaflet in my Angular.js map application. One of my resources requires an authorization header with token. I am using the leaflet-realtime plugin (found here: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) to get map updates and therefore need to be able to specify my header when realtime performs a fetch to get the data.

I first tried using another library, fetch-intercept (found here: https://github.com/werk85/fetch-intercept), to intercept the requests and attach the header, but the interceptor was being ignored. I included a console.log in the interceptor and it was never reached.

After more research, I noticed specifying headers is supposed to be supported: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/pull/83. However, I cannot find an example for how to properly attach an authorization token. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
this.mapRealtime = L.realtime({
  url: this.getRealtimeUrl(),
  crossOrigin: true,
  headers: {"Authorization": "token"},
  type: 'json',
},
```

However, when I check the Network logging from my web browser (Chrome) debugging console, all I see for the Request Headers is:

Provisional headers are shown

Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization

Access-Control-Request-Method: GET

and the server returns status 403 with errortype MissingAuthenticationTokenException.

Can anyone provide an example of how to correctly attach the token? Thanks!

Comment: “Provisional headers are shown” typically indicates the browser is loading the response from its cache. So you might want to check in a different browser, and force reload/clear the browser cache in whatever browser you’ve already been testing with

Comment: Thanks, sideshowbarker! I will try this out to get more information.

Comment: Looks like the token is not being set in FireFox, Chrome, or Edge.

Comment: @briR Hi any luck with this?facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The realtime Leaflet only take url or json file path and  you will be unable to pass headers(auth) as they have patch for it which is not working. I was facing same issue. What I did is following:

```
 realtime = (L as any).realtime(async function (success, error) {
    let geodataJson = await self.updateGeoJson();
    success(geodataJson);
  }, {
    interval: 15 * 1000,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,......
```

I have pass funtion to realtime and in that function I called simple API with headers

```
async  updateGeoJson() {
await this.api.getMarkersGeoJson().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.geoData = res;
});
return this.geoData; }
```

On first call it will not get data  in from this function so we also need to load data in **this.geoData** in **ngOnInit** before **initmap**.
For me it is working I know this is just work around but this issue is still in leaflet realtime. Hopefully this will work for you